# How to show the sum is zero

Tags: combinatorics

Let $E_N = \{ (e_1, e_2, ... , e_N): e_j \in \{-1, 1\} \}$.  Now for each fixed $e = (e_1, e_2, ... , e_N) \in E_N$ there are $\binom N 2$ products of the form $e_ie_j$ for $i \neq j$.  Note that each of these products is either $-1$ or $1$.  Now let $c_+(e)$ be the number of products of the form above that equal $1$ and let $c_-(e)$ be the number of products of the form above that equal $-1$.  I claim that: $\sum_{e \in E_N}(c_+(e) - c_-(e)) = 0$

Can anyone help me prove this?

Comment: All summands are positive... do you mean $-c_-(e)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Assuming OP meant to have $-c_-(e)$ in his sum):

First, \begin{eqnarray*} \sum_{e\in E_n}(c_+(e)-c_-(e)) &=& \sum_{e\in E_n}\sum_{i=1}^N\sum_{j=i+1}^N e_ie_j \\ &=& \sum_{i=1}^N\sum_{j=i+1}^N\sum_{e\in E_n} e_ie_j.\end{eqnarray*}

Fix a pair $i,j$ with $1\leq i<j\leq N$. Observe that there are exactly $2^{N-2}$ elements $e\in E_N$ with $e_i=e_j=1$, $2^{N-2}$ elements with $e_i=1,e_j=-1$, $2^{N-2}$ elements with $e_i=-1$, $e_j=1$ and finally $2^{N-2}$ elements with $e_i=e_j=-1$.

So within your sum, $$\sum_{e\in E_n} e_ie_j = 2^{N-2}-2^{N-2}- 2^{N-2}+2^{N-2} = 0.$$ Since this is true for all pairs $i,j$, this proves your claim.